# How to use a saved model in Keras to predict and classify an image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I trained a model hand position classifier with Keras and I ended up saving the model with the code (model.save('model.h5') )
now i'm traying to predict an image using this model is it doable? if yes could you give me some examples please ?
PS:my data is provided as a CSV file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to import the saved model using `load_model` function.

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('model.h5')
```

Before you will predict the result for a new given input you have to invoke `compile` method.

```
classifier.compile(loss='your_loss', optimizer='your_optimizer', metrics=['your_metrics'])
```

After compiling, you're done to deal with new images.

```
from keras.preprocessing import image

test_image= image.load_img(picturePath, target_size = (img_width, img_height)) 
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = numpy.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
test_image = test_image.reshape(img_width, img_height)
result = model.predict(test_image)
```

Comment: first thank you for your response,in my model input_size=36 should i resize my image?

Comment: when i run your code i get the following error :python2.7/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 360, in load_img
    raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `array_to_img` requires PIL. and Pil is already installed do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Jennifer95, array_to_img is a method from `keras.preprocessing`

Comment: yes @Mihai ,i have fixed the error by installing  " pillow" ^^

Comment: @Jennifer95, please accept the answer in order to help other people.

Answer (score 0):

when i run the code posting by @Mihai Alexandru-Ionut

```html
# dimensions of our images
img_width, img_height = 313, 220

# load the model we saved
model = load_model('hmodel.h5')
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy','mse'])

test_image= image.load_img('/Images/1.jpg',target_size = (img_width, img_height))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = model.predict(test_image)
```

i get the following error: line 113, in _standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 313, 220, 3)
could somoeone help me to fix this error

Comment: You can use `reshape` method. Have a look to my updated answer.

Comment: i added a piece of code "test_image = test_image.reshape(img_width, img_height)",now getting this error ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 206580 into shape (313,220) .can you please tell me how to size of new dimensions could not get my answer to problem .PS 206580=3*313*220

Comment: i tryed to run this pices of code "x= scipy.misc.imread('/Images/1.jpg').shape" and i have got this result "(313, 220, 3)".have you any suggestion?

Comment: Try this: `test_image = test_image.reshape(img_width, img_height, 3)`

Comment: i try it and i have this error:ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (313, 220, 3)

Comment: You need something with 2 dimensions but the product must be equal to `206580`. You can try something like this: `test_image = test_image.reshape(img_width, img_height * 3)` but I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have shape (36,) but got array with shape (660,).sorry i have no idea in order to solve this error .I'm thinking to resize my image but it will be too small !!! could you help me please

Comment: you have to reshape your image size in order to correspond to required size. From your error I see that your first neural network layer has 36 units , so you need to have 36 columns to your image width and height will be 206580/36

Comment: thank you ,but i didn't find solution to my problem yet

Answer (score 0):

Here I am providing an example of saving a tensorflow.keras model to `model_path` folder under current directory. This works well with most recent tensorflow (TF2.0.0rc2). I will update this description if there is any change in near future. Follow the example code below and change data loading, shape etc.

## Saving and loading entire model

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

#import data
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

# create a model
def create_model():
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    ])
# compile the model
  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

# Create a basic model instance
model=create_model()

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)
loss, acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test,verbose=1)
print("Original model, accuracy: {:5.2f}%".format(100*acc))

# Save entire model to a HDF5 file
model.save('./model_path/my_model.h5')

# Recreate the exact same model, including weights and optimizer.
new_model = keras.models.load_model('./model_path/my_model.h5')
loss, acc = new_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print("Restored model, accuracy: {:5.2f}%".format(100*acc))
```

`model.save` approach saves everything:

- The weight values
- The model's architecture
- The optimizer configuration
- Training config (what passed to compile)

As `model.save` saves training config, we don't need to compile the model after restoring using `keras.models.load_model`